# Animate Compose GoogleMap to a Specified Location

Tags: android, google-maps, android-jetpack-compose, google-maps-compose

I am working on a simple Maps App and I am trying to make [GoogleMap](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/maps-compose) composable ***zoom-inanimation***  over 1000 ms duration.

So far I have this code:

```
Column( ... ) {

                val destinationLatLng = LatLng(destination.lat, destination.lng)
                
                val cameraPositionState = rememberCameraPositionState {
                    position = CameraPosition.fromLatLngZoom(destinationLatLng, 15f)

                }

                GoogleMap(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                        cameraPositionState = cameraPositionState
                        //stuck on animating this
                )

            }
```

In the old good GoogleMap view I could animate the camera with this sample code.

```
googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition), 1000, null)
```

However, in Compose I am unable to re-engineer this to achieve the zoom-in animation.

I have looked at the docs for [Compose for the Maps SDK](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/maps-platform/compose-maps-sdk-android-now-) and [Maps Compose Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/maps-compose) but I am still stuck.

Please let me know if there is a way to animate camera in Compose GoogleMap

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If it's one and only one time animation when your Composable is composed use LaunchEffect(key1 = true) as the code shows below.

```
val initialZoom = 6f
val finalZoom = 15f
val destinationLatLng = LatLng(destination.lat, destination.lng)

val cameraPositionState = rememberCameraPositionState {
    position = CameraPosition.fromLatLngZoom(destinationLatLng, initialZoom)
}

LaunchedEffect(key1 = true) {
    cameraPositionState.animate(
        update = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(
            CameraPosition(destinationLatLng, finalZoom, 0f, 0f)
        ),
        durationMs = 1000
    )
}

GoogleMap(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    cameraPositionState = cameraPositionState
)
```

Comment: Genius, it is working! Thanks, @MS2099 for having a look.